# C# - Wait and Check three times before throwing exception

Tags: c#

Here is the existing code. I am trying to refactor this code.

What is the best way to implement this using C#

The first time, I want to wait for 200ms, 2nd time 400 and 3rd time 600

```
await Task.Delay(200);
var category = this.categoryRepository.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);
if (category == null)
{
    await Task.Delay(400);
    category = this.categoryRepository.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);
    if (category == null)
    {
                await Task.Delay(600);
                category = this.categoryRepository.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);

      if (category == null)
      {
          throw NullReferenceException;
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Personally, I would not do this here.  Let your code throw like it is supposed to and put that logic into whoever is catching the exception down the line.

Comment: Polly. Specifically the RetryPolicy.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Looks like you are trying to sync some threads by waiting until the data is available. Why not wait on the other thread/data directly?

Comment: The "don't do that" comments should be answers, especially since OP said they're refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Add a counter and use a loop:

```
int numTries = 0;
Category category = null;

do
{
    numTries++;

    await Task.Delay(200 * numTries);
    category = this.categoryRepository.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);
} while (category == null && numTries < 3);

if (category == null)
{
    throw new NullReferenceException();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that `throw NullReferenceException;` is valid C# syntax

Comment: ^^ I fixed it. Feel free to revert if that's not what you wanted, @itsme86

Comment: I guess that was a C&P from question, @PavelAnikhouski

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above only slightly cleaner in my opinion

```
int retires = 6;
Category category = null;
while (retries-- > 0 && catagory == null)
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    category = this.categoryRepository.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);
}

if (category == null)
{
    throw NullReferenceException;
}
```

I wouldn't wait longer each time as it will just slow down performance, instead just increase the number of retries.

Comment: But not equivalent, especially considering _"The first time, I want to wait for 200ms, 2nd time 400 and 3rd time 600"_ ...